# Topics sinking if not answered directly

Tags: discussion, questions

Since when you press the unanswered button you are suggested only recent unanswered but the truth is some of them are never really answered wouldn't it be better to suggest a better sorting algorithms ? For example ananswered and old topics first ?

Answer (score 2):

There are already four tabs under Unanswered that you can click to get different sort orders.

- my tags
- newest
- votes
- no answers

If you want to see the oldest unanswered questions, you can already go to the last page of the "newest" tab with just one extra click.

I don't think questions sinking into obscurity is caused by anything happening on the Unanswered page. Most people either look at the front page of the site, newest questions, or their favorite tags. If a question falls through the cracks, it can be revived with a substantial edit, or by placing a bounty.

Comment: `If you want to see the oldest unanswered questions, you can already go to the last page of the "newest" tab`, that's **all** oldest though, not oldest unanswered.

Comment: @MrLore No, [those](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=35827&tab=newest) are the oldest unanswered questions.